# How to apply CSS to a string variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css class .table1 and i need to apply it in a string i created in JavaScript. Is there any specific element that helps me add it?

I have tried setAttribute but it turned out undefined

```
JavaScript:
<script>
var c = "<table><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>";
</script>
CSS:
<style>
.table1 { background-color:cyan; color:red; }</style>
```

I need to apply (.table1) to the string c, but i am not figuring it out.
 Any constructive comments or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't changing your string so it was `<table class='table1'>` be easiest?

Comment: Hi Elio - the simplest answer to your question is to simply specify `<table class='table1'>...</table>` in your string. However, the bigger question is, how are you using the value in `c` within your page itself?

Comment: The string is not an HTML element so you cant apply any css to it. The best you can do is append `class='table1'` to the `<table>` tag in your string in case you render it to html later on.

Comment: Yep, it worked, i do not know why i didn't think of that, anyway thank you all, and @Forty3  im using it for a select dropdown , onChange it displays the table :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what others have suggested in the comments, another option is to use [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to recreate the table that way. Then, you can do `setAttribute` like you wanted to. Using it would go something like this.

```
let table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute('class', 'table1');
let firstRow = document.createElement('tr');
let firstElement = document.createElement('td');
firstElement.textContent = '1';
firstRow.appendChild(firstElement);
table.appendChild(firstRow);
....
```

And so on and so forth. This could obviously be simplified and made shorter with loops, but it is an alternative method.

Comment: Ah yep this works too, but what if it is a very large table tho?

Comment: Yeah that's the downside with this method. But the thing with tables is that there's usually patterns, and you could do an entire row at a time in a for loop. And I would argue it isn't any more feasible to store an entire table in one string.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
document.write("<style>.table1 { background-color:cyan; color:red; }</style>");
```